# How to implement charts in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, charts

I am developing one iOS application and in that I have to show some statistical representation of data with charts.
Now what I want to know is what should be better?

1. use UIWebview and show some html charts in that UIWebview

   ```
    OR
   ```
2. use native IOS library like [coreplo](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)t

I don't know which one is better... I just want some standard performance with some responsive UI (LINE Charts , Pie Charts , Bar Charts).

Can anyone please suggest me any helpful tips and solution?

Comment: If your graphs are simple use UIWebview, in my opinion core-plot is good rather for more complex representations of data

Comment: my data will be not more complex but it will have more number of data..in thousands or in lacks

Comment: If I was you I'd use core-plot in that case, more work with it, but you won't have to worry if it can ahndle your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements I would say using a HTML/Javascript based library would be the preferred solution. I've been using both types for different projects; [Core-plot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) like you mentioned, and [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) with jQuery mostly. I would break it down like this:

If you already have the data and just want to show it; it won't change, you don't want to do anything else with it, just display it right now in the simplest possible way, I would say go with a web view and display it there (I haven't had any trouble displaying thousands of data points so far if that is of concern).

On the other hand if you're downloading the data and it might change between sessions (maybe you'll have multiple datasets in the future), if you want to make some kind of computation or derive other statistics from it, or just have more detailed control over both the data and the graphing I can definitely recommend Core-plot or some similar native library.

Comment: thanx for the answer....made it clear for me